# Notepad++ replace text

Tags: notepad++

Here's what im trying to achieve using notepad++:

i have .txt file containing the fowling:

```
@@@
Some text here
Some text here
Some text here
Some text here
@@@
Some text here
Some text here
Some text here
@@@
Some text here
Some text here
@@@
```

i need to make it look like this:

```
"Some text here
Some text here
Some text here
Some text here"
"Some text here
Some text here
Some text here"
"Some text here
Some text here"
```

I read a lot of examples for extended replacing, including inside notepad++ site, but couldn't figured out how to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using extended search

replace \r\n@@@\r\n with "\r\n"
replace @@@\r\n with "
replace \r\n@@@ with "

it can be done it one step with a (more complicated) regex, but I'm not sure you need that.